# remove uiwebview href grey selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

i have searched the net, but the given solutions doesn't fit my needs..
So i have a webview, and my webview loads data like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[_webView loadHTMLString:htmString baseURL:baseURL];
```

That html string has anchor tags with href e.g - < a href=http://url.com/ ... /> and i trigger some events on shouldStartLoadWithRequest.

Now the problem is i don't know how to remove the grey selection when this attribute is pressed. I saw people are doing this:

```
<a href=http://yourlink.com/ style = "-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);">
```

and some similar things, but i want to do it other way. By other way i'm talking that i don't want to change my htmlString, because it may have a lot of them, and injecting style in every seems not the perfect solution..

So i tried doing like this:

```
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitTapHighlightColor = \"rgba(0,0,0,0);\""];
```

after i load html string, but it doesn't work.

So anybody has some suggestions, or knows what am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Or maybe a simple injection of javascrypt for the behavior i want?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView

    NSString *js = @"var styleNode = document.createElement('style');\n"
                    "styleNode.type = 'text/css';\n"
                    "var styleText = document.createTextNode('a {-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}');\n"
                    "styleNode.appendChild(styleText);\n"
                    "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleNode);\n";

    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

Comment: Super!!! Exactly what i was looking for!! Thank you very much! I've edited your answer a bit and even disabled the touch callout :)) Wouldn't have done it without your help!

Comment: This is excellent advice. Thanks! I basically ripped the js in a separate js file that I've been using for my webview but this way is great too especially if you want the js snippet controlled in isolation.